# How to convert array string to attribute?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I need to call `JSON` value by array value, how to do that?

```
var key = ['name','address'];

for(let i=0; i<key.length; i++){
   console.log(response.data.data.key[i]); // nothing happen
}
```

Comment: Could you post more of your code? There is no indication what `response` is, what it contains, where it gets initialized, or its possible structure.

Comment: response.data.data is json data, normally I call it like : response.data.data.name, but I want to call it by array value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for bracket notation

```
var key = ['name','address'];

for(let i=0; i<key.length; i++){
   console.log(response.data.data[key[i]]); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic property notation:

```js
var response = {
  data: {
    data: {
      name: "Jack",
      address: "Unknown"
    }
  }
};

var key = ['name', 'address'];

for (let i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
  console.log(response.data.data[key[i]]);
}
```

Comment: Many years on stackoverflow make use code clairvoyants :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach()` to make a single liner code:

```js
var response = {
  data: {
    data: {
      'name': 'someName',
      'address': 'someAddress',
      'age': 10
    }
  }
}
var key = ['name','address'];

key.forEach((i) => console.log(response.data.data[i]));
```